# How to fix UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have a fingerprint scanner project. It is working fine before I update android studio to build gradle 3.5. And know I encounter this error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lhlh.fpscanner-Y9B8PCb-5rg-DCor7GqdfQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lhlh.fpscanner-Y9B8PCb-5rg-DCor7GqdfQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libfgtitinit.so"
```

From what I understand the error message says that "libfgtitinit.so" can't be located in the following directory.

This error is not new for me, whenever I encounter this error after update I use the following steps to fix the problem:

> 1. remove .jar library dependencies and .so files
> 2. clean project
> 3. re-add libraries and .so files
> 4. gradle sync
> 5. invalidate cache/restart

but it does not work this time around.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, can i ask, did you provide abi filters in your default config under NDK? can you post build.gradle?

Comment: no there are no abiFilters in my build.gradle. 
The current project is working fine if I revert to the previous build gradle but I was wondering why this error exist if updated to the latest version.

Comment: cant say why specificaly 3.5 giving errors but If you want to use 3.5 u can try and follow instructions in this blog https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d

Comment: thanks it work. How to vote your answer?

Comment: its alright, you can add answer yourself and mark it correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [Sahdeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7910735/sahdeep-singh), I have fix my project by adding abiFilters in the build.gradle.

Please use this [link](https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d) for references.

> This help me fix my project but would like to know why updating to build.gradle 3.5.0 broke my project ? It was from version build.gradle 3.4.2 and there was no abiFilters found in my gradle but the project is working fine. I would like to know the reason if somebody know why?.

Comment: But now "The option 'android.useDeprecatedNdk' is deprecated.
The current default is 'false'.
It has been removed from the current version of the Android Gradle plugin.
NdkCompile is no longer supported"